# MysqlConnector special character in string connection

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

I use MySqlConnector to make a connection to a database. When constructing my connection string the user has a password which contains a special character ("€") and his password is "€ test". The fact that this character is passed to the connection string returns the "acces deined" error.
Do you know what to do to allow the connection with this type of character in the password?

```
 string connStr = server=127.0.0.1;user=test;database=EXPERT_alpha;port=3306;password='€test'; convert zero datetime=True;Pooling=False;
```

mySQlCnx = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
mySQlCnx.Open();

Comment: you say that the password is `€ test`, but in your connection string you've written `€test` - did you miss that space in your actual code, or is that just an error in your question? (also: strings are usually surrounded by `"` quotes `"`.)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `&euro;` instead of €?

```
 string connStr = server=127.0.0.1;user=test;database=EXPERT_alpha;port=3306;password='&euro;test'; convert zero datetime=True;Pooling=False;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with the connection line server=127.0.0.1;user=test;database=EXPERT_alpha;port=3306;password='&euro;test'; convert zero datetime=True;Pooling=False;
But I still have the same problem.

Comment: @cyril.S Was there a space between the euro character and test or not? Your question was unclear... make sure the space is there if that's the actual password. You should also try €test without the single quotes

Comment: Thank you for your return, initially the password defined is € test (without space) I defined it.
i think this is related to mysqlconnector (https://mysqlconnector.net/). via another connector the problem is not present (ex libmysql)

Comment: @cyril.S According to MySQL documentation you’re missing double quotes around the connection string and should have no quotes around the password - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html

Comment: '&euro;' is an html character entity, but usually not known by xml